# How do I extend my ubuntu partiation after I removed the windows partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I installed dual boot and decided to remove to windows partition. I used gparted to do this. As you can see in the image I have some allocated space now. My question is, whether it is possible to extend the sda6 partition into the uncatalogued space. The problem is that I can't move anything around and there is now option to extend it using the resize/move option.

[image: Screenshot gparted]

Comment: The partition as shown is in-use (ie. mounted), it needs to be unmounted before you can re-size it.  It's easiest to do this via 'live' media  (ie. boot your Ubuntu install media, use 'try ubuntu' and then re-size).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **move** the /dev/sda6 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda6 to the right, to the desired size
- click the Apply icon

Answer (score 0):

First you need to boot from a liveUSB and use gparted to resize the partition.

As an alternative consider simply creating another partition in the unallocated space and use it maybe as a home partition. More information on how to do this [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving).